# DISTINCT on a single column

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm using spring data JPA along with Hibernate. I have to find all entries by id, however I'm selecting only some of the columns.

I managed to do this by using specified constructor

```
@Query("SELECT new Foo(f.field1, f.field2, f.field3)
        FROM FooTable f WHERE f.field1 = :field")
```

I need to make `field1` as a `DISTINCT`, however putting this column into `DISTINCT(field1)` doesn't work.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: JPQL [doesn't support](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_select_clause) `distinct` with parameter. What do you need to achieve?

Comment: I have two fields with timestamp, `field1` and `field2`. First one is logging only, the second one is containing more important timestamp. Sometimes it happens that `field2` has same date for couple rows, I want to distinct that - in that case logging timestamp has different dates, hence I'm getting duplicated more important values.
Other option is to removei t on front-end side.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Query("SELECT new Foo(f.field1, f.field2, f.field3) 
        FROM FooTable f, FooTable f2
        WHERE f.field1 = :field
        AND f.field1 != f2.field1")
```

Note that it'll miss the `null` values.